# Populate node image field with files submitted by webform?

Tags: entities, webforms, media

Just wondering if this can be done in any way.

I have a block webform which is shown in a give node, let call this node Page-1.

The Page-1 node has a multivalue image field.

You can attach files to the webform (using https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file).

Now let's say I submit the webform with 3 images attached, then my question: is there any way to populate the image field of the Page-1 node with those images?

Answer (score 1):

Any issues with using: [hook_webform_submission_insert](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) and copy these images to current viewing node?

If node ID isn't available in webform submission, you can always put hidden field to webform with a NID.